# How to expand multiple macros based on variadic macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I have many macros that end up generating code. For example:

```
#define CODE_GEN_IDENT1_HDR(PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3) \
   // code generated

#define CODE_GEN_IDENT2_HDR(PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3) \
   // code generated

#define CODE_GEN_IDENT1_SRC(PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3) \
    // code generated

#define CODE_GEN_IDENT2_SRC(PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3) \
    // code generated
```

The idea is that `HDR` generates functions definitions and `SRC` generates their implementation. All macros have the same amount of arguments (in this example, 3). `IDENT` can be any name like `MATH`, `TRIG`, `ALGS`, `CONTAINERS`, etc. This is what I want to focus on.

I'm trying to build up a macro that can generate all of these macros macros with different `IDENT` using variadic macros. For example:

```
// Concatenate macros to a standard form
#define CONCATH_(C) CODE_GEN_##C##_HDR
#define CONCATC_(C) CODE_GEN_##C##_SRC

// CONCATH concatenates to HDR
// CONCATC concatenates to SRC
#define CONCATH(C) CONCATH_(C)
#define CONCATC(C) CONCATC_(C)

#define MASTER_MACRO(PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3, ...) \
    // Code that generates all other macros
    // using CONCATH and CONCATC
    // how could this be done?
```

When I write:

```
MASTER_MACRO(int, "Hello", char *, MATH, TRIG, CONT)
```

I would like to have something like:

```
CODE_GEN_MATH_HDR(int, "Hello", char *)
CODE_GEN_TRIG_HDR(int, "Hello", char *)
CODE_GEN_CONT_HDR(int, "Hello", char *)
CODE_GEN_MATH_SRC(int, "Hello", char *)
CODE_GEN_TRIG_SRC(int, "Hello", char *)
CODE_GEN_CONT_SRC(int, "Hello", char *)
```

To somehow access the given arguments and concatenate each, making both header and source.

What I currently have is a fixed length macro like:

```
MASTER_MACRO(PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3, MATH, TRIG, CONT, DUPL, SORT) \
    CONCATH(MATH)(PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3)
    CONCATH(TRIG)(PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3)
    ...
    CONCATC(MATH)(PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3)
    ...
```

And when the user doesn't want to generate `CONT`, `DUPL` or any other macro he's got to pass in a pre-defined argumet like `_` meaning he is not wanting to generate that and having an empty macro:

```
#define CODE_GEN___SRC(PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3) // Empty
```

But this is not good enough. On different projects these different `IDENT` have different names, so having to make new master macros are a bit annoying.

But the big questions are:

- Can this be done?
- Is there a simple way to do this?
- Can it be done using only standard C (no compiler-dependent macro)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  For a hand rolled implementation, you probably want to start with a basic argument counter like this:

```
#define COUNT(...) \
        COUNT_I(__VA_ARGS__, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,)
#define COUNT_I(_          ,_9,_8,_7,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2, X,...) X
```

The argument counter works kind of like a "shift register", injecting the argument list before the count.  If called with one argument, everything aligns X with 1.  Each additional argument shifts this list over... 2 arguments shifts 2 into X, 3 shifts 3 in, and so on.  This is just the basic form, supporting up to 9 arguments, to convey the idea.

...now you can generate variadic macro utilities like this one:

```
#define GLUE(A,B) GLUE_I(A,B)
#define GLUE_I(A,B) A##B
#define TRANSFORM_CD(MACRO, ...) GLUE(TRANSFORM_CD_,COUNT(__VA_ARGS__))(MACRO,__VA_ARGS__)

#define TRANSFORM_CD_1(MACRO,X) MACRO(X)
#define TRANSFORM_CD_2(MACRO,X,...) MACRO(X),TRANSFORM_CD_1(MACRO,__VA_ARGS__)
#define TRANSFORM_CD_3(MACRO,X,...) MACRO(X),TRANSFORM_CD_2(MACRO,__VA_ARGS__)
#define TRANSFORM_CD_4(MACRO,X,...) MACRO(X),TRANSFORM_CD_3(MACRO,__VA_ARGS__)
#define TRANSFORM_CD_5(MACRO,X,...) MACRO(X),TRANSFORM_CD_4(MACRO,__VA_ARGS__)
#define TRANSFORM_CD_6(MACRO,X,...) MACRO(X),TRANSFORM_CD_5(MACRO,__VA_ARGS__)
#define TRANSFORM_CD_7(MACRO,X,...) MACRO(X),TRANSFORM_CD_6(MACRO,__VA_ARGS__)
#define TRANSFORM_CD_8(MACRO,X,...) MACRO(X),TRANSFORM_CD_7(MACRO,__VA_ARGS__)
#define TRANSFORM_CD_9(MACRO,X,...) MACRO(X),TRANSFORM_CD_8(MACRO,__VA_ARGS__)
```

Conceptually `TRANSFORM_CD` is meant to "transform" a Comma Delimited list (args 2 and up) to another comma delimited list by applying a macro to it.  In this case, we start with a comma delimited list of base names (what you call `IDENT` here) and apply one of your transform macros to it; for example, `TRANSFORM(CONCATH, TRIG, CONT, DUPL)` expands to `CODE_GEN_TRIG_HDR, CODE_GEN_CONT_HDR, CODE_GEN_DUPL_HDR`.

Next we need something to generate calls with multiple macros and the same parameter set; like this utility:

```
#define INVOKE_ALL(TUPLE_, ...) GLUE(INVOKE_ALL_,COUNT(__VA_ARGS__))(TUPLE_,__VA_ARGS__)

#define INVOKE_ALL_1(TUPLE_, X) X TUPLE_
#define INVOKE_ALL_2(TUPLE_, X,...) X TUPLE_ INVOKE_ALL_1(TUPLE_,__VA_ARGS__)
#define INVOKE_ALL_3(TUPLE_, X,...) X TUPLE_ INVOKE_ALL_2(TUPLE_,__VA_ARGS__)
#define INVOKE_ALL_4(TUPLE_, X,...) X TUPLE_ INVOKE_ALL_3(TUPLE_,__VA_ARGS__)
#define INVOKE_ALL_5(TUPLE_, X,...) X TUPLE_ INVOKE_ALL_4(TUPLE_,__VA_ARGS__)
#define INVOKE_ALL_6(TUPLE_, X,...) X TUPLE_ INVOKE_ALL_5(TUPLE_,__VA_ARGS__)
#define INVOKE_ALL_7(TUPLE_, X,...) X TUPLE_ INVOKE_ALL_6(TUPLE_,__VA_ARGS__)
#define INVOKE_ALL_8(TUPLE_, X,...) X TUPLE_ INVOKE_ALL_7(TUPLE_,__VA_ARGS__)
#define INVOKE_ALL_9(TUPLE_, X,...) X TUPLE_ INVOKE_ALL_8(TUPLE_,__VA_ARGS__)
```

Here, `TUPLE_` is meant to be a parenthesized argument list (this makes the utility a bit more generic than requiring it support exactly three parameters); and each other parameter represents a macro to be called with those arguments.

Combining the two, this:

```
INVOKE_ALL((p1 a1, p2 a2, p3 a3),TRANSFORM_CD(CONCATH,MATH,TRIG,CONT,DUPL))
```

...should expand to (reformatted for clarity):

```
CODE_GEN_TRIG_HDR(p1 a1, p2 a2, p3 a3)
CODE_GEN_CONT_HDR(p1 a1, p2 a2, p3 a3)
CODE_GEN_DUPL_HDR(p1 a1, p2 a2, p3 a3)
```

...and if you really want, you could preserve `MASTER_MACRO`'s form and function, simply making it variadic, like this:

```
#define MASTER_MACRO(PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3, ...) \
    INVOKE_ALL((PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3),TRANSFORM_CD(CONCATH,__VA_ARGS__)) \
    INVOKE_ALL((PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3),TRANSFORM_CD(CONCATC,__VA_ARGS__))
```

[demo at stacked-crooked](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/852929bdd79d1f65)